# How can i get the user in firebase database, to write from a component with vuejs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

hope can some one help me, i´m beguinner on this.
I´m using vuejs, firebase, for to write in the database from a vue component. I already had the auth working and the writting; but i want that each user write in his own component, and not all users in the same component. this is my code:

> users login in this component(login.vue):

```
<template>
<div>

<h2> auth </h2>

   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2">
       <div class="login card-panel green white-text center">
         <h3>Login</h3>
         <form action="index.html">
           <div class="input-field">
             <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
             <input type="email" id="email" v-model="email">
             <label class="white-text" for="email">Email Address</label>
           </div>
           <div class="input-field">
             <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
             <input type="password" id="password" v-model="password">
             <label class="white-text" for="password">Password</label>
           </div>
           <button v-on:click="login" class="btn btn-large btn-extended 
            grey lighten-4 black-text">Login</button>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
name: 'login',
data: function() {
 return {
  email: '',
  password: ''
 };
},
methods: {
login: function(e) {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
    .then(
      user => {
        alert(`You are logged in as ${user.email}`);
        this.$router.go({ path: this.$router.path });
      },
      err => {
        alert(err.message);
      }
    );
  e.preventDefault();
 }
}
};
</script>
```

> then in this (envio.vue)component the user write and send to firebase:

```
<template>
 <div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="enviarMensaje">
      <textarea v-model="boton1" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
      <br>
      <textarea v-model="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje">
  </form>
  <hr>
  <h1>texto con idicaciones</h1>
 </div>
</template>


<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { contenidoFormulario } from '../firebase'

 export default {
  data: function() {
  return {
  mensaje: null,
  boton1: null,
  usuario: '',
  }
 },

 methods: {
  enviarMensaje(){
   contenidoFormulario(uid).set({
      mensaje: this.mensaje,
      boton1: this.boton1,
      usuario: this.usuario,
   })
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

> and this is the firebase database json:

https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/

Project

-- formularioContenido:

```
     boton1: "..."

     mensaje: "..."

     usuario: "..."
```

> and i need somthing like this:

Project

-- formularioContenido:

```
     --user A

          boton1: "..."

          mensaje: "..."

          usuario: "..."

     --user B

          boton1: "..."

          mensaje: "..."

          usuario: "..."
```

> '../firebase'  code:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase';



const app = initializeApp({
    apiKey: """",
    authDomain: """
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: ""
    messagingSenderId: ""
});


export const db = app.database();
export const contenidoFormulario = db.ref('formularioContenido');
```

> main.js

```
let app;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (!app) {

   app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {uid: null}, 
   router,
   template: '<App/>',
   components: { App }
 });
```

}
   });

> my logout:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
<section>

   //...

  <li v-if="isLoggedIn"><button v-on:click="logout" class="btn 
   black">Logout</button></li>

</section>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
  name: 'navbar',
  data() {
   return {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    currentUser: false,
  };
 },
  created() {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
     this.isLoggedIn = true;
     this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
  }
 },
  methods: {
   logout: function() {
     firebase
     .auth()
     .signOut()
     .then(() => {
      this.$root.uid = null;   //just added
      this.$router.go({ path: this.$router.path });
     });
    }
   }
  };

  </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i want that each user write in his own component"? Are you referring to a view component in this sentence?? Or more to a specific database node "attached" to the user? It is not crystal clear what you are attempting to do. Also, how do you call the enviarMessaje method? What is the value of the uid parameter when you call this function?

Comment: thanks for asking @RenaudTarnec, this <script> is part of my vue component, when any user login can send infromation to the database in firebase and change the content; now what i need is when each user write and send the infromation, it get save in the database child (one child per user), at the moment there is only one child, and all the users can edit it. So, the problem is that i am not calling the uid correctly, i've tried different ways, without success.

Comment: Then show more code. Show the code you are fetching from firebase the data you are trying to modify. The code you use to save it, etc. For starters.

Comment: @acdcjunior thnxs, i just did it.

Comment: Show `contenidoFormulario` definition in `'../firebase'` file

Comment: @acdcjunior just did it

Comment: @acdcjunior, the child in the database cames up, but only one; i need one child per user.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? The data will be inserted at `db.ref('formularioContenido/' + uid);`

Comment: @acdcjunior, yes i did. and I just add my 'main.js' and my 'logout'.

Comment: Did you add `this.$root.uid = user.uid;` in the login? Did you use like `contenidoFormulario(this.$root.uid).set({` in the component?

Comment: yes, exactly as you indicated me in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to save the `uid` upon login, so you can use it later.

The best way to handle that would be using Vuex, but, without better knowledge of your app, the simplest way is just to create a `uid` property in the `data` of your root component, like.

```js
// probably main.js file
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {uid: null}, // added this
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

Then it will be globally available as:

```js
this.$root.uid
```

And you can update it as:

```js
this.$root.uid = 'newUserId';
```

Having it that way, you can consider that, if `$root.uid` is set, then the user is logged in.

So, to set it, change your login method:

```js
methods: {
login: function(e) {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
    .then(
      user => {
        alert(`You are logged in as ${user.email}`);
        this.$root.uid = user.uid;                       // added this
        this.$router.go({ path: this.$router.path });
      },
      err => {
        alert(err.message);
      }
    );
  e.preventDefault();
 }
}
```

Then turn `contenidoFormulario` into a function like:

```js
export const contenidoFormulario = (uid) => db.ref('formularioContenido/' + uid);
```

And, when using it inside a component, do:

```js
 methods: {
  enviarMensaje(){
   contenidoFormulario(this.$root.uid).set({        // changed here
      mensaje: this.mensaje,
      boton1: this.boton1,
      usuario: this.usuario,
   })
  }
 }
```

That should work.

Note: don't forget to put somewhere in your code `this.$root.uid = null;` for **logout**.

Note[2]: Since you are using Firebase, I recommend you take a look in [**vuefire**](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire). It makes the integration much easier.

Comment: **EDIT:** Renamed `$uid` to `uid`. When prefixed by `$`, vue picks up from options.